# Microsoft SQL найти максимум

Tags: sql, access, vba

Мне нужна функция Last_g, которая возвращает максимум из всех значении столбца "Группа". Ошибка в строке Last_g = rst.Fields("Группа")
Как победить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

У вас столбец не имеет имени. Напишите так:

```
select max(Группа) as Группа from Товар
```

Comment: Теперь вышла такая ошибка: Псевдоним Группа из списка определений select запроса привёл к возникновению циклической ссылки.

Comment: Назовите стобец иначе.

Comment: Вы думаете сработает такая строка: select max(Группа1) as Группа1 from Товар  ?

Comment: Нет. Похоже, этот код не вы писали.

select max(Группа) as Группа1

...

 Last_g = rst.Fields("Группа1")

Comment: В смысле не я?! А кто ж ещё то?